# Is there easy way to get the peak and the lowest in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For consider my data in the following format:

```
20180101,10
20180102,20
20180103,15
....
```

The first is date and the second is how many products are sold, instead of insert all these into a database, and use a select max xxxx SQL statements to find out what is the max number during a period, is there any shorthands or useful library can serve this purpose? Thanks.

Comment: you need to define your "period". Is that month, quarter or year in your case?

Comment: youz can load all these in tuples and use a `maximum = max( your_tuplelist, key = lambda x:x[1])` - same for min ... if you need to get it over a period of more then 1 date you could use `groupby` from `itertools` over a sorted list and a grouping-criteria that is following your period-criteria and use that max. All in all this is all a bit vague - or call it **broad**

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is the lib you want.

Let me show you with an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# let's build a dummy dataset
index = pd.date_range(start="1/1/2015", end="31/12/2018")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=len(index)),
                  columns=["sales"], index=index)

>>> df.head()
            sales
2015-01-01     32
2015-01-02      0
2015-01-03     12
2015-01-04     77
2015-01-05     86
```

Now let's say you want to aggregate sales on a monthly basis:

```
>>> df["sales"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1M")).sum()

2015-01-31    1441
2015-02-28    1164
2015-03-31    1624
2015-04-30    1629
2015-05-31    1427
[...]
```

Or a semester basis

```
df["sales"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="6M", closed="left", label="right")).sum()    
2015-06-30    8921
2015-12-31    9365
2016-06-30    9820
2016-12-31    8881
2017-06-30    8773
2017-12-31    8709
2018-06-30    9481
2018-12-31    9522
2019-06-30      51
```

*for some reason `Grouper` binning with six months freq has some issue with 31/12 sales and it puts them into a new bin in 2019, looking into it will let you know if I find anything... or if anyone else want to comment please do*

Or you want to know which one was the best semester:

```
>>> df["sales"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="6M")).sum().idxmax()              
Timestamp('2016-06-30 00:00:00', freq='6M')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a biased answer but pandas is really good for handling data like this. While you can accomplish this kind of operation using tuples, lists, etc.
pandas offers much more functionality. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[20180101,15], [20180102,10], [20180103,12],[20180104,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['date', 'products'])
# if your data is in csv, excel, database... whatever... you can easily pull
# df = pd.read_csv('name') || pd.read_excel() || pd.read_sql()
df
Out[2]: 
       date  products
0  20180101        15
1  20180102        10
2  20180103        12
3  20180104        10

# It helps to use datetime format to perform operations on the data
# Operations make reference to an "index" in the dataframe
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y%m%d")  #strftime format
df
Out[3]: 
                date  products
date                          
2018-01-01  20180101        15
2018-01-02  20180102        10
2018-01-03  20180103        12
2018-01-04  20180104        10

# Now we can drop that date column...
df.drop(columns='date', inplace=True)
df
Out[4]: 
            products
date                
2018-01-01        15
2018-01-02        10
2018-01-03        12
2018-01-04        10

# Yes, there are ways to do the above in shorthand... lots of info on pandas on SO
# I want you to see the individual steps we are taking to keep simple

# Now is when the fun begins
df.rolling(2).sum()  # prints a rolling 2-day sum
Out[5]: 
            products
date                
2018-01-01       NaN
2018-01-02      25.0
2018-01-03      22.0
2018-01-04      22.0

df.rolling(3).mean()  # prints a rolling 3-day average
Out[6]: 
             products
date                 
2018-01-01        NaN
2018-01-02        NaN
2018-01-03  12.333333
2018-01-04  10.666667

df.resample('W').sum()  # Resamples the data so you can look on a weekly basis
Out[7]: 
            products
date                
2018-01-07        47

df.rolling(2).max() # max number of products over a rolling two-day period
Out[9]: 
            products
date                
2018-01-01       NaN
2018-01-02      15.0
2018-01-03      12.0
2018-01-04      12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `pandas`

assuming that your date column is called 'date' and that it is a datetime dtypes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('date')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).max()
```

would give you each month max. freq could be changed to whatever frequency you like.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the comment from @Patrick Artner:

```
a = (20180101,10)
b = (20180102,20)
c = (20180103,15)
d = (a,b,c)
maximum = max( d, key = lambda x:x[1])
minimum = min(d, key= lambda x:x[1])
print(minimum)
```

Maybe this gives some inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

Please if this is the desired result.

```
data = [{'date':1, 'products_sold': 2}, {'date':2, 'products_sold': 5},{'date':5, 'products_sold': 2}]
start_date = 1
end_date = 2
max_value_in_period = max(x['products_sold'] for x in data if x['date'] >= start_date and x['date'] <= end_date)
print(max_value_in_period)
```